# How to make a bot in Windows that does automated search of domain names to see if they are available?

Tags: web-crawlers, python, automation

Instead of manually typing in domain names in a domain search registry to see if they are available,

How to program a bot to run through a pre-specified list of .com domain names by searching each one in sequence at a registrar like namecheap.com? For example, give the bot a list of 8-letter English names, and search each one individually to see if it's available? (the point of the question isn't about infinite combinations of the alphabet, so let's just say its a finite list of 30 prospective names)

First thought would be to use automated browser `selenium` for the python programming language, but how do they do this?

Comment: Do you actually want to program a bot or do you want to search for domain availability in bulk? If you have the pre-specified lists, there are plenty of registrars that will accept uploads of .txt or .csv files. The registrar you mentioned even has a form that will take 5,000 words/domains at a time (Bulk domain search). Unless you have something else in mind... but when you say pre-specified lists I just assume you have the lists already and you don't need the bot.

Comment: could you link the namecheap batch form. Pre-specified lists, or bot-generated lists (which would be even more automated), I'm interested in both

Comment: Take a look and see if this will do what you need - https://www.namecheap.com/domains/bulk-domain-search/ - If you do decide you want a bot, just know that most/all registrars will try to block you. It's very inefficient to do it one by one either way. Bot or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a bash script for it. Put your domain names to check in `domains.txt`, one domain per line, then run the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAINS=~/domains.txt

while read -r domain; do
  whois $domain | grep -qci "No match"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # found
    echo $domain
  fi
done < $DOMAINS
```

This prints out only the domains that are available.

Adapted from [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/433328/466439).

Comment: does bash language only work in linux. never heard of it. any solution for windows?

Comment: @user610620 you could (ab)use CygWin, or do it in civilized way through Windows Subsystem for Linux. Or just go for PowerShell.

Comment: not familiar with any of these, sorry. I've edited the question to Windows to source alternatives

Comment: Just because you've never heard of it doesn't mean that it's not a good solution. This can be made to work under Windows pretty easily with cygwin.

Comment: no offense. but as you can tell I never heard of bash, cygwin, etc so there would be a steep learning curve for me. this is not a fault on your part or the answer you've contributed here. but there's too much don't-know-how operability barriers here for a newbie to take on for a simple task

Comment: [Here's how to run a bash script on windows.](https://appuals.com/how-to-execute-sh-files-on-windows/). In answering this question I saw terms like "bot, automated, and selenium" and I assumed that you were either writing something for linux or had linux tooling installed on your windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video explanation exactly with python and selenium
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wB3cTma0xs

Comment: Although that link may be useful you should put the core contents in the answer as that link may one day be removed and this answer will be useless without it.

Comment: @manqlele hope you could give a short summary of the steps walked through in the video for back up

Comment: The steps are in the video...that is why I posted it :D and @JohnConde is right about the link, but I don't know how to do it myself, just remembered that I once watched this video and thought it may help you